# How to find and classify the singularities of $\frac{e^{-z} \sin(2(z-1)^2)}{(z^2-4)(z-1)^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How to find and classify the singularities of $$\frac{e^{-z} \sin(2(z-1)^2)}{(z^2-4)(z-1)^2}$$

Here is what I have:

I think the singularities are all isolated and are located at $z=1,\pm2$.

I have managed to calculate the residues at $\pm2$ by using the fact that they are simple poles and using the limit expression to find the residues I get

$$Res(f,2)=\frac{e^{-2} \sin(2)}{4} \\ Res(f,-2)=-\frac{e^{2} \sin(18)}{36}$$

Which I'm not too sure on, then I have no idea how to figure out the residue at $1$ it is a pole of order $2$ but I'm not sure how to evaluate it as the limit involves a nasty derivative.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the residues you calculated are correct.

Comment: Okay any  idea how to get the third one? The residue at $1$?

Comment: the residue is the coef $c_{-1}$ of the Laurent series

Comment: Are you sure $z=1$ is a pole?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal : you are right, didn't notice  the $\sin \ldots$

Comment: @DanielFisher : you should instead try on $\frac{e^{-z} \sin(2(z+1)^2)}{(z^2-4)(z-1)^2}$  the residue at $z=1$

Comment: I don't know what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the residue at the "double pole" at $\;z=1\;$ :

$$\lim_{z\to1}\left((z-1)^2 f(z)\right)'=\lim_{z\to1}\left(\frac{e^{-z}\
\sin(2(z-1)^2)}{z^2-4}\right)'=$$

$$=\lim_{z\to1}\frac{2ze^{-z}\sin(2(z-1)^2)-(z^2-4)\left((-e^{-z}\sin(2(z-1)^2+4(z-1)e^{-z}\cos(2(z-1)^2)\right)}{(z^2-4)^2}=$$

$$=\frac{0+3\left(0\right)}{(-3)^2}=0$$

which doesn't surprise much since

$$\lim_{z\to1}\left(\frac{\sin(2(z-1)^2)}{(z-1)^2}\right)=\lim_{z\to1}\;2\;\left(\frac{\sin(2(z-1)^2)}{2(z-1)^2}\right)=2\cdot1=2$$

and thus $\;z=1\;$ is in fact a removable singularity, not an actual pole!

Comment: I think I get it now, so it is a removable singularity so Res(f,1)=0

Comment: @DanielFisher No, that only gives you the residue (or the coefficient $\;c_{-1}\;$ in the correspondent Laurent series). In this case, the residue is zero, which does **not** necessarily mean the singularity is removable but gives you a hint. The existence of that squared sine makes it clearer, in my opinion.

Comment: @DanielFisher Exactly, that is the correct direction: if it is a removable singularity then the Laurent series is going, in fact, to be a power one and thus the residues is zero.

Comment: I'm confused again? According to my book if $\lim_{z \to 1}f(z)$ exists (which you pretty much have) then it says the singularity is removable and the residue is $0$ is this incorrect?

And since it is removable then we can define the function on a ball centred at $1$ and the Laurent series will then be a Taylor series i.e $c_{-1}=0$

Comment: The implication "removable singularity $\implies$ residue is $0$" is correct. And the implication "residue is $0$ $\implies$ removable singularity" is false.

Comment: @C.Dubussy Thank you, exactly so. I hope the asker will have it clearer now.

Comment: Okay thanks got it.